# Need help for Haskell regular expression

Tags: regex, haskell

Given some strings: `"\begin"`, `"\end"` or `"\section"` etc.

I want to match them with following function and regular expression:

```
matchTest (mkRegex '\\[:alnum:]+')  "\begin"
```

I always get False when I test it in GHCi,

Does anyone know how to match the pattern like `"\begin"` or `"\end"` etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
> matchTest (mkRegex "\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+") "\\begin"
True
```

There are a couple of issues with your line of code.

- The regular expression isn't quoted correctly, the string needs to be within double quotes. (But you should get a syntax error for that.)
- The regular expressions supported by `regex-compat` (I assume that's the package you're using) are the same as those supported by `egrep`, and they don't know `:alnum:`.
- Backslash `\` is an escape character both within Haskell strings and regular expressions, so you need to escape it.